# Dangling pointer issue C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dangling-pointer

I'm making a game engine and I have run into a problem with destroying elements.

For example I have some cameras that follow and look at an target (a gameobject or an actor).
Later in the game the camera target is destroyed and the camera code will crash because the code will try to access to a freed object and I want to avoid this crash.

So here is a simplified code example:
I have an instantiated object, an int for example, to keep things simple.
I have several references to this object.
If the instantiated object is deleted, I'd like to be able to check if the object still exists or not if one of my scripts wants to access to the destroyed object.

```cpp
int* refToMyInt = nullptr; //I want to possibility to have empty pointer
int* refToMyInt2 = nullptr;

int* myInt = new int(2);
refToMyInt = myInt;
refToMyInt2 = refToMyInt;

delete myInt;

if(refToMyInt == nullptr && refToMyInt2 == nullptr)
  std::cout << "myInt Deleted!" << std::endl; // Never called
```

Except that it doesn't work, delete doesn't seem to change the variables to `nullptr`.
I don't want to manually set `refToMyInt` and `refToMyInt2` to nullptr because I could have dozens of references to that object.
I've found a solution but it was to use `weak_ptr` and I'd like to avoid using it because using the `lock()` function to access the values each time is a bit cumbersome and impractical...

Is there another solution? Thank you!

Comment: `delete` doesn't modify the pointers.

Comment: In the case where you can't use a container from the standard library, look into smart pointers that c++ has had since 2011: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and stop using `new`

Comment: And unless your example is just a simplified (*too* simplified IMO) example of your real code, then don't have pointers to simple types. That almost never makes sense. I also suggest you take some time to step back to your requirements, the analysis of the requirements, and the design. Does the requirements, analysis and design really motivate the use of pointers?

Comment: You are using `new` too much. Learn to use the standard library containers like `std::vector`, and if (and only if) you really need to manually allocate memory (usually only for polymorphic classes) then use [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). See [R.11 C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete). I only ever expect to see new/delete inside a datastructure class nowadays. And any raw pointer I see I expect to be non-owning (or to be a reference if it always needs to refer to a valid object)

Comment: Also please be careful with your naming... The variables that begin with `ref` are *pointers*, not references. That could lead to confusion in the future.

Comment: After the `delete myInt;` line, add this line:  `myInt = reftoMyInt = refToMyInt2 = nullptr;`  That should take care of the problem.  It's the programmers responsibility to keep those things in order.

Comment: @Eljay I think it is the repsonsibilities of teachers not to teach new/delete as a basic C++ feature. I know datastructure teachers still think they need to teach it, but all they teach is "datastructures using some (legacy features of) C++" instead of teaching C++.

Comment: @PepijnKramer • Kate Gregory [Stop Teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) (as in "stop teaching C++ as if it were C"), from CppCon 2015.  I haven't needed to use `new` in my real project since we upgraded the project from C++98 to C++14.

Comment: I know.. same here since C++11. And from that moment the memory leak bugs all gone.

Comment: *"I'd like to avoid using [`weak_ptr`] because using the `lock()` function to access the values each time is a bit cumbersome and impractical..."* -- it shouldn't be significantly more cumbersome/impractical than checking for null before accessing the pointed-to object. (Compare `if (target != nullptr)` to `if (auto locked = target.lock())`.) Are you sure you want to expressly forbid `weak_ptr` as an answer to this question, simply because your attempt to use it was cumbersome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"I'd like to avoid using it because using the lock() function to access the values each time is a bit cumbersome and impractical."**

This might be true for `*(ptr.lock())` vs `*ptr` but this is a false comparison. You should always check if `ptr` is a `nullptr` before dereferencing it:

```cpp
if (ptr != nullptr) {
  auto value = *ptr;
}
```

and that is only marginally more verbose than:

```cpp
if (auto sptr = ptr.lock()) {
  auto value = *sptr;
}
```

**Answer:**

The solution is a combination of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`.

Instead of:

```cpp
int* refToMyInt = nullptr; //I want to possibility to have empty pointer
int* refToMyInt2 = nullptr;

int* myInt = new int(2);
refToMyInt = myInt;
refToMyInt2 = refToMyInt;

delete myInt;

if(refToMyInt == nullptr && refToMyInt2 == nullptr)
  std::cout << "myInt Deleted!" << std::endl; // Never called
```

you can write:

```cpp
std::weak_ptr<int> refToMyInt;
std::weak_ptr<int> refToMyInt2;

std::shared_ptr<int> myInt{ new int(2) };

refToMyInt = std::weak_ptr<int>(myInt);
refToMyInt2 = std::weak_ptr<int>(myInt);

myInt.reset();

if(refToMyInt.expired() && refToMyInt2.expired())
  std::cout << "myInt Deleted!" << std::endl; // Never called
```

I kept the original variable names to make comparisons easier.

Answer (score -1):

These examples will show you a bit more of the intended use of vector/make_unique.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// dynamic memory allocation is mostly only necessary
// for polymorphic classes (e.g. classes derived from
// an abstract baseclass)

class my_interface
{
public:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
    virtual ~my_interface() = default;
protected:
    my_interface() = default;
};

// 

class my_concrete_class :
    public my_interface
{
public:
    my_concrete_class() = default;

    // to show my_concrete_class 
    // instance will be deleted by smart pointer.
    ~my_concrete_class()
    {
        std::cout << "my_concrete_class destructor\n";
    }


    void do_something() override
    {
    }

    
};

int main()
{
    int my_int{ 1 };
    int& ref_to_my_int{ my_int }; // no & this ensure a ref is always refering to a valid object
    int* ptr_to_my_int{ &my_int }; // non-owning pointer https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r3-a-raw-pointer-a-t-is-non-owning

    ref_to_my_int = 42; // modify through reference
    std::cout << "my_int now has value " << my_int;

    // create a scope that determines life cycle of my_concrete_class.
    {
        std::cout << "entering scope 1\n";
        std::unique_ptr<my_interface> itf_ptr{ std::make_unique<my_concrete_class>() };
        std::cout << "going out of scope , unique_ptr will be destructed\n";
    }

    {
        std::vector<int> values{ 1,2,3 }; // will dynamically allocate memory for 3 ints 
        std::cout << "vector going out of scope, will delete allocated memory\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```